# Uploading multiple files from ios photos app

Tags: javascript, iphone

Is there a way to control the **pie chart loading icon** in IOS using javascript when a user uploads multiple media? We want to directly use our own progress bar. This has caused confusion in our user base and majority are thinking that our site froze due to a delay after selection. Please see the [Screenshot of the photos gallery during upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jChxy.jpg)